# Google Chrome Dev Tools - can't work out font-family

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I've got the following bit of text on a website:

[image: caption]

which, when I select in Dev Tools and filter by font-family, gives me the following:

[image: Dev Tools snippet 1]

and, further down:

[image]

Why are all the font-family attributes greyed out and how is this piece of text getting its font?

==== UPDATE

Just to clarify, I don't see a `font` attribute being set either. Shouldn't this element inherit from `body`? If so, why don't I see that in Dev Tools?

==== UPDATE 2

Looking in the Computed tab I see at the top:

[image: Dev Tools Computed tab top]

and at the bottom:

[image: Dev Tools Computed tab bottom]

I assume the font is Courier 13. But:

1. what is the Show inherited properties checkbox?
2. what are all the lines below "font-family: monospaced, serif"?
3. and how is that Courier 13 font being chosen (from one of those Style sheet entries in point 2 above)?

Comment: Something that i can say is that that's a SERIF font, so it can be useful in your reseach, but i'm pretty sura that you're setting a font family somewhere else

Comment: The cross-out means that a different definition has gained precedence over the one you're looking at. You can read more about css specificity here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Did you check **computed styles** in Dev Tools?

Answer (score 4):

In dev tools there is `computed` tab. This will show you the currently implemented values for all properties on the currently selected element.

[image]

You can scroll down in this tab to find what `font-family` being used. As for why it is not showing what font-family you are using in the filters, dunno.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have a font: attribute somewhere? it may contain the font family.

```
font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
```